# Use mobile microphone from NATIVE app made with meteorjs

Tags: cordova, meteor

I thought of an use case where I would want authorized devices to automatically enable my mic and record audio for 15 seconds and send it to me.

I thought of using Meteor for this because I do not know how to make android/iOS apps.

1. How can I use the phones microphone from an app built with meteor?
2. And how to do it in a manner that doesn't require the client to give permission to the app every time it wants to access the mic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish these kinds of extensions into "native" land, i.e., go beyond the usual webview capabilities cordova is using, by adding plugins to your build. For the capability in question, you could check out the [Capture](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_media_capture_capture.md.html) plugin.

The [documentation](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Meteor-Cordova-Phonegap-integration#using-cordova-plugins-directly-in-your-application) shows how to add such plugins to your project.